# Can I make a link which changes ending based on user input without javascript?

Tags: php, html

I would like to have a URL such as

- www.google.com/

and a user input text area.

If the user inputted **123** the link would be

- www.google.com/123

and there would be a button they could click to go to this link.

Could someone please tell me if this is possible without javascript or if not? Could you please let me know how best to implement it? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by posting your form to a PHP page and PHP will redirect the user to that URL using [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="urlpart" />
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

And then at the top of your page put:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    header('location: http://www.google.ca/'.$_POST['urlpart']);
    exit();
}
```

Please take great care in how you implement this because it can easily lead to XSS injections.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This seems to work. However, when I first click the submit button I am directed to another link where I can then click on the button again and it works. Is there a way to make sure that the URL the button takes me to is always the one I specify?

Comment: Might be easier to use a get form with the actual destination site. Though the php method will work if you use a different form of redirect, like:

Comment: Might be easier to use a get form with the actual destination site. Though the php method will work if you use a different form of redirect, like:  header('HTTP/1.1 302'); header('location: '.$url); as above. It's also possible that your browser is diplaying a page before redirecting on it's own though that usually happens with meta redirect not http status redirects.

Answer (score 0):

If the link you want is in a query string (example: `http://google.com/search?q=blah+blah+blah`) then you can just use a form with the url as the action and the method `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a link using `label` tag, of course you will only be able to change the part of url after `?` symbol. Live example with link to google (opens in new window, so you can still have the fiddle page): http://jsfiddle.net/xCbSD/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a form that users a server-side script (such as PHP as used below) and the get method. Here is an example of such a script;

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="input" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This script should create a form with a textbox and a submit button. If a user were to enter 123 into the textbox and click submit, the resulting URL should look like this;

www.yoursite.com/index.php?input=123

A simple mod_rewrite similar to the one shown in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxXhjSqcHdg) should allow you to rewrite this URL as;

www.yoursite.com/123

Note: for security reasons, it is best to filter or sanitise any input that the user enters, otherwise your site would be vulnerable to hacking, such as SQL injection and cross-site scripting attacks.